# How can I get video size from FFmpegStream

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am trying to get video metadata from a video using ffmpeg. I am using the following dependency,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.bramp.ffmpeg</groupId>
   <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am unable to get the video size using the following code snippet,

```
        FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe();
        FFmpegProbeResult metadata = ffprobe.probe("/tmp/" + filename);
        List<FFmpegStream> streams = metadata.getStreams();

        for (FFmpegStream stream : streams) {
            videoProperties.put("bitrate", stream.bit_rate);
            videoProperties.put("frameRate", stream.avg_frame_rate.toString());
            videoProperties.put("size", stream.nal_length_size);
            videoProperties.put("resolution", stream.width + "X" + stream.height);
            videoProperties.put("duration", new Double(stream.duration).toString());
            videoProperties.put("codec", stream.codec_name);
            videoProperties.put("CodecType", stream.codec_type.name());
        }
```

stream.nal_length_size always returns null. Kindly provide your inputs to get the video size.

Any inputs here really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply using Java's `java.io.File`

```
long fileSize = new File("/tmp/" + filename).length();
```